# Como puedo eliminar una cookie usando jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

estoy trabajndo un login usando cookies para guardar al usuario, pero al momento de hacer logout usando jquery quiero que elimine la cookie para que tengo que auntentificarse otra vez, como puedo hacer eso?

intente esta linea que encontre en internet:

```
 $.removeCookie('Usuario', { path: '/' });
```

la cookie se llama usuario pero en el explorador me marca un error al querer usar ese metodo, me dice que .removeCookie no es una funcion.
Tengo agregadas estas dos librerias:

```
<script src="../jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="carhartl-jquery-cookie-92b7715/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
```

Comment: Prueba cambiar el plugin por [este](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js)

Comment: ¿Estas seguro de que el `path` es correcto? Porque si el error es `removeCookie is not a function`, seguramente es porque el `path` al archivo esta mal.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí tienes la biblioteca que te falta

[GitHub](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie#readme)

La última version 
[GitHub](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie)